# How to set a GIT HUB user in .travis.yml?

Tags: github, travis-ci

How to set a **GITHub user name** in the below Git clone command?. I am new to GIT HUB and planning to keep this command in `.travis.yml` file.

My `.travis.yml` file should execute irrespective of the Git Hub user. Could you please help me in setting this up.

```
git clone https://github.com/**gitgubusername**/repositoryname/
```

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is public, you don't need to setup a user.
The git clone command itself will be enough.

Travis will infer the url from where the `.travis-ci.yml` file is.

For private repos accessed by Travis, see "[Private Dependencies](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies)".

Comment: I am using public repository. git clone it self will not give the desired result i guess. Could you please tell me the complete command to fetch repository from individual users (Unique script in yml file should fetch the users repository)

Comment: @RameshThoomu Travis is in charge of the git clone. So there is no script with a "git clone/fetch" in it. Just a `.travis.yml`